# Is searching for a specific table faster than searching for a particular entry in a particular table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, sqlite, database-design, postgresql

I need to create a history table for particular resource and am trying to decide how to design it. My current thought was to create a separate table for each instance of the resource and enter a new value whenever there is something to new add. Would that be quicker? Or should I try to put everything in one table and search through it? I am not too sure how to fit it in one table yet but I figured knowing if there would be a speed hit would be a good start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a history, it would be simple enough to have a table like...

```
history_id | resource_id | history_event
1          | 1           | created
2          | 1           | updated with silly info
```

With an index on `resource_id` it will be plenty fast. :)

Comment: Thanks! Any idea how to create a new resource_id in Rails when creating a new instance of the resource? I was thinking about using a global variable but I don't think the model would have access to that. Either way I am hoping for a better solution

Comment: Your resource will automatically get assigned an id when it is stored to the database or when you use the `Resource.create` method. :)

Comment: Right, but as I understand it, each row will be given a new id. I need an id for each instance of the resource, so the id should be able to repeat every time there is a new update.

Comment: Right. `history_id` is a primary key, and thus will be completely unique every time you get a new row. `resource_id` is NOT unique in this case. You'd have your own `resource` table and its primary key would be `resource_id`, so when you enter into it, it would get a new `resource_id` on each insert. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you are looking for [acts_as_audited](https://github.com/collectiveidea/acts_as_audited).

Answer (score 1):

If the data logically belongs in one table, put it in one table. Don't prematurely vertically or horizontally partition your data unless you have a good reason.

Comment: Following your suggestion tends to make unique keys needlessly complex, though. It's usually better to materialize the live row in a separate table.

Comment: I'd agree with Denis, and add that the tables that store current and historical information have different predicates (different meanings), which is a red flag at the theoretical level. (A red flag that should warn you against combining both into a single table, that is.) For me, "different predicates" counts as a very good reason.